# How to fix screen tearing in Kubuntu with Nvidia graphics card?

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, kde

This seems to be a recognised issue with KDE and Nvidia, but the suggested fix hasn't worked for me.

The suggested fix is to add one of these lines to the /etc/profile.d/kwin.sh file and reboot (only try the second if the first doesn't work, and don't use both at once):

export __GL_YIELD="USLEEP"

export KWIN_TRIPLE_BUFFER=1

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my screen tearing on Kubuntu with `export __GL_YIELD="USLEEP"` as `/etc/profile.d/kwin.sh` like you have and `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvidia-drm.modeset=1"` with kernel parameters (and update grub!).

Have you tried this yet?

Comment: Thanks,  I hadn't tried adding that to the grub, it has actually stopped the tearing! But there is still stuttering and lagging, such as in a fast moving part of a video or when resizing a window. Do you this problem as well?

Comment: Compared to Windows 10, yes. From my experience, many desktop environments just aren't as smooth as you expect it to be. This could be just my card though (gtx 1080).

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, such a relief not to have the screen tearing, was driving me mad! Yes I think the screen stuttering etc. might just be because I am looking too closely at the screen, it does seem that Windows 10 is smoother though, which is annoying as I thought KDE was supposed to be one of the best desktop environments for linux